# Rewrite Engine Multiple Rules

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I am looking to create a few rewrite rules. Here are the types of urls I want to change.

`http://www.mysite.com/profile/kwelch` change to `profile.php?username=kwelch`

Here is the line I have for that:
`RewriteRule ^profile/([^/.]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1`

I am also looking to rewrite all ages to add the `.php` to any page.

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L, QSA]`

I would like to have these work together and also add more that have the same logic as the first.

Other urls:

`http://www.mysite.com/wof/vote` change to `vote.php?type=wof`
`http://www.mysite.com/wof/nominate` change to `nominate.php?type=nominate`

I would like to add more to the url such as user id if possible.

I have attempted to add my two lines together and they work beautifully seperately but the page errors and shows a 500 error.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's foremost a matter of order: [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)

Your rule to add the extension should be the first, and slightly adapted however:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

This ensures it only rewrites requests which really exist as .php script. An assertion in the RewriteRule like `(?<!\.php)` might have the same effect. (Much simpler would be resorting to `MultiViews` in place of this RewriteRule.)

And lastly you might have luck with adding `[L]` to each further rule. This prevents loops in the rewrite engine, which I suspect is what your unspecified error is about.

Comment: Can you give more example on how they work together? I tried this and adding the others with the last flag but I am still not getting the desired output. The error is still just a plain 500 error.

Comment: The `error.log` makes guessing the actual 500 cause redundant.

Comment: I found the issue it was with the flags. I had a space between the flags.